# Strange null character sequence in output file

Tags: c++, file-io, ofstream, null-character

I write a graph to a simple text file format (adjacency list). In one instance, I discovered that the resulting file contains a strange very long line of "NUL" characters.

[image]

Where might these null characters come from? What do they mean?

The code that produces the file is

```
void GraphIO::writeAdjacencyList(Graph& G, std::string path) {
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open(path.c_str());

    G.forallNodes([&](node v) {
        file << v;
        G.forallNeighborsOf(v, [&](node x) {
            file << " " << x;
        });
        file << std::endl;
    });
    INFO("wrote graph to file: " << path);
}
```

Iteration over all nodes is realized as:

```
template<typename Callback>
inline void EnsembleClustering::Graph::forallNodes(Callback func, std::string par) {
    assert ((par == "") || (par == "parallel"));
    int64_t n  = this->numberOfNodes();
    #pragma omp parallel for if (par == "parallel")
    for (node v = this->firstNode(); v <= n; ++v) {
        // call node function
        func(v);
    }
}
```

EDIT: the type `node` is simply a typedef for `int64_t`

Comment: And output operator for node?

Comment: parallel writes to an ofstream? is that safe?

Comment: `forallNodes` accepts a string but you don't pass it one inside `writeAdjacencyList`. What gives?

Comment: @jrok The string `""` is passed as default argument.

Comment: @DariuszWawer I think that the write is not parallel since the argument `par` is `""` by default, not `"parallel"`.

Comment: @ForEveR `node` is `int64_t`

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong in this code, perhaps the bug is in `forallNeighborsOf`. In any case, it's hard to visually debug partial code, so try producing a minimal testcase.

Comment: @jrok I don't think I can produce a testcase which you would consider minimal, since `forallNeighborsOf` depends on library code (research code) which is not my own. It's almost as difficult as building the entire project.

Comment: You can try creating a minimal graph that reproduces the problem and then check after each write when the nulls are written.

Comment: @dutt Okay I'll try. But I do not know on which kind of graphs this problem appears.

Comment: but you gave us a screenshot of such a file? otherwise it seems you have a bit of work to do :)

Comment: Such messed up output is probably the result of lacking synchronization around writing the output.

Comment: I'm also facing this problem. Did you found the reason for this?